# Gulp.watch tasks not called (gulp 4.0.0)

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have just migrated an old project from gulp 3 to gulp 4.0.0. I'm having trouble making gulp.watch tasks run within my watch function. I'm running on Windows.

The watch function is as follows:

```
function watch(done) {
  gulp.watch(LAYOUTSFILES, copytosomelocation);
  gulp.watch(MODULEFILES, copymodulestosomelocation);
  gulp.watch(DLLFILES, gacdeploy);
  gulp.watch("./Styles/**/*.less", cssless);

  console.log("watching");
  done();
}
```

Locations are formatted as follows (worked in gulp 3, so locations are at least correct):

```
let LAYOUTSFILES = [
  "./Folder/Project/**/*.*"
];
```

This is the first task being called:

```
function copytosomelocation() {
  console.log("In copy");
  return gulp.src(LAYOUTSFILES)
    .pipe(fileCache.filter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OUTLAYOUTS));
}
```

At the end of the gulpfile, I have `exports.watch = watch;`.

When I run, I get the following output:

```
[18:43:59] Using gulpfile 
D:\git\repo\folder\someproject\gulpfile.js
[18:43:59] Starting 'watch'...
watching
[18:43:59] Finished 'watch' after 17 ms
```

That is to say
- No files are copied
- No output is logged to the console from function copytosomelocation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had neglected to take the necessary task dependency changes with me to the new structure.

The original watch function was structured as follows:

```
gulp.task("watch", ["webpack-watch"], () => { ... });
```

which described a dependency on the following:

```
gulp.task('webpack-watch', (done) => {
  runWebpack(["-d"], true, done);
});

function runWebpack(params, watch, done) {
  params = params || [];
  params.push("--color");
  if (watch) {
    params.push("-w");
  }
  if (watch) {
    spawnCommand("webpack", params);
    done(); //return immidiately when watching
  } else {
    spawnCommand("webpack", params, done);
  }
}
```

Without this functionality gulp was watching a directory which would only be updated when webpack-watch had run. I solved this by updating the watch export as follows:

```
exports.watch = gulp.series('webpack-watch', watch);
```